# how to created a variable numer elements in listview android

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make a listView that display a question witt a variable numbers of checkBoxs. I'm using a class that extends BaseAdapter. My problem come when the list need to scroll and then get rows repeated. I know where is my error but I cant get a solution. I need to extract part of the code out of the metod getView, like I did in title of the question but I cant make for the rest, Please help.

```
private class AdaptadorListaPreguntas extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> array;
    public AdaptadorListaPreguntas(ArrayList<String> lista){
        array=lista;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        HolderListaPreguntas holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        String frase = array.get(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {

            holder = new HolderListaPreguntas();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_multiple_eleccion, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            //Count how many checkbox i need
            for (int i=0 ; i<frase.length(); i++){
                if (frase.charAt(i) == '\n'){
                    nCheckBox++;
                }
            }
            //Rest one, need for the format of the string
            nCheckBox--;

            for(int i=0; i<nCheckBox; i++){

                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext(),null,android.R.attr.checkboxStyle);

                cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_multiple_eleccion);

                //Put checkbox in to layout
                holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxmultiple);
                holder.layout.addView(cb);
            }

            //reset for next loop
            nCheckBox = 0;
        }

        else{
            holder = (HolderListaPreguntas) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tituloPregunta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulopreguntamultple);
        holder.id = position;
        holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxmultiple);


        //Get text for each CheckBox
        int indice = frase.indexOf("-");
        String titulo = frase.substring(frase.indexOf(")")+1, frase.indexOf("-", indice+1));
        holder.tituloPregunta.setText(titulo);

        //Put all elements of layout in array
        ArrayList<View> respuestas = holder.layout.getTouchables();

      //Format of the text (only need "question") -Question;/;(id:n)(vof)
        int indPriPreInit = frase.indexOf("-", frase.indexOf("-")+1);
        int indPriPreFin= frase.indexOf(";/;");

        //put text in the checkbox
        for (View cb : respuestas){
            if(cb instanceof CheckBox){

                indPriPreInit = frase.indexOf("-", indPriPreInit);
                indPriPreFin = frase.indexOf(";/;", indPriPreFin);

                if (indPriPreInit > -1 && indPriPreFin > -1){
                    String textoCheckBox = (String) frase.subSequence(indPriPreInit, indPriPreFin);
                    indPriPreInit = indPriPreInit+1;
                    indPriPreFin = indPriPreFin+1;
                    //Relleno el texto del checkbox
                    ((CheckBox) cb).setText(textoCheckBox);
                }
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont have time to read the code now but what you must do is: {loop - add question {loop - add check-boxes} }. I suspect from what I've seen in your code that you add questions and check-boxes in the same loop.

Comment: Change code, simplified and anotations in eng. Now works fine but... 5 row onwards gets values of 1 row onwards(5 row - 1 row, 6 row -2 row, ....) I mean, checkbox of row 5 check when checkbox of row 1 are check, same for row 6-2, 7-3... :S

Comment: Your question is not clear...Explain the issue again.

Comment: I have a listview, in each row i need to created a varible number of checkbox. The problem come when row go out of screen. I try whit 7 row and works fine, except that the checkbox of row 5 check the checkbox of the row 1 when i preses (and row 1 same for row 5), and same for row 2-6, 3-6, 4-7. I think the problem come when the row is outside the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i decided to use a scrollView instead a listView, the reason is the listView use a recycle system that i dont want to use and its the problem!

I found more info of How Work a ListView in: [Link](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AdaptadorListaPreguntas extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private final ArrayList<String> array;
    private final List<Set<Integer>> checked;

    public AdaptadorListaPreguntas(ArrayList<String> lista){
        array=lista;
        checked = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>(lista.size());
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        HolderListaPreguntas holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        String frase = array.get(position);
        int checkboxCount = frase.split("\n").length-1;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new HolderListaPreguntas();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_multiple_eleccion, parent, false);
            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxmultiple);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (HolderListaPreguntas) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Set<Integer> current;
        try {
          current = checked.get(position);
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            current = new HashSet<Integer>(checkboxCount);
            checked.set(position, current);
        }

        List<CheckBox> respuestas = new ArrayList<CheckBox>(checkboxCount);
        holder.layout.removeAllViews();

        for(int i=0; i < checkboxCount; i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext(),null,android.R.attr.checkboxStyle);
            cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_multiple_eleccion);
            respuestas.add(cb);
            cb.setTag(position);
            if (current.contains(position))
                cb.setChecked(true);
            holder.layout.addView(cb);
        }

        holder.tituloPregunta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulopreguntamultple);
        holder.id = position;
        holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxmultiple);


        //Get text for each CheckBox
        int indice = frase.indexOf("-");
        String titulo = frase.substring(frase.indexOf(")")+1, frase.indexOf("-", indice+1));
        holder.tituloPregunta.setText(titulo);

        //Format of the text (only need "question") -Question;/;(id:n)(vof)
        int indPriPreInit = frase.indexOf("-", frase.indexOf("-")+1);
        int indPriPreFin= frase.indexOf(";/;");

        //put text in the checkbox
        for (CheckBox cb : respuestas){
            indPriPreInit = frase.indexOf("-", indPriPreInit);
            indPriPreFin = frase.indexOf(";/;", indPriPreFin);

            if (indPriPreInit > -1 && indPriPreFin > -1){
                String textoCheckBox = (String) frase.subSequence(indPriPreInit, indPriPreFin);
                indPriPreInit = indPriPreInit+1;
                indPriPreFin = indPriPreFin+1;
                //Relleno el texto del checkbox
                cb.setText(textoCheckBox);
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int position = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)buttonView.getParent();
        List<View> touchables = vg.getTouchables();
        int index = touchables.indexOf(buttonView);
        if (isChecked) {
            checked.get(position).add(index);
        } else {
            checked.get(position).remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but have a problem. I try this before but when you make scroll you loose the scheckbox check state because the checkbox are created again when the row are load again. I think you need to created the checkbox inside if (convertView == null).
Thanks for the try

Comment: Set<Integer> current = checked.get(position); Fail here ////
09-24 15:54:00.016: E/AndroidRuntime(8402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 15:54:00.016: E/AndroidRuntime(8402): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service k2.sistema.servicio.ServicioNotificaciones@4147bbf8 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException ////

I think checked must be iniciated first